# If statement scenario

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

All,

I have a scenario where I want to exit sub if ("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" and either CBL or RBL does not equal zero. I thought the below code would work however if CBL = 0 and RBL = 100 the code will not exit sub.

```
 Dim CBL As Long
 CBL = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(97, Yearcol).Value
 Dim RBL As Long
 RBL = Worksheets("Summary").Cells(101, Yearcol).Value

'Check if prestage two projects
    If Worksheets("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" And RBL Or CBL <> 0  Then
```

Comment: `If Worksheets("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" And RBL <> 0 Or CBL <> 0  Then`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax (and conditions) are:

```
If Worksheets("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" And (RBL <> 0 Or CBL <> 0)  Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: He expects to exit code if RBL Or CBL does **not** equal to 0, so I guess what you meant is `If Worksheets("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" And (RBL <> 0 Or CBL <> 0)`

Comment: This is what he wrote (highlight by myself): "I want to exit sub if ("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" and either CBL or RBL **does not equal zero**"

Answer (score 0):

You need to evaluate each condition, so this does not work:

```
RBL Or CBL <> 0
```

This is because you are only evaluating `CBL`. In order to evaluate that neither `RBL` nor `CBL` equals to 0, you need to check them individually, like so:

```
RBL <> 0 OR CBL <> 0
```

Since you want to evaluate that one of the conditions above is `TRUE` but also that `Worksheets("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes"` you need to enclose the second portion of your code into parenthesis, so the following will work as expected:

```
If Worksheets("Summary").Range("C17").Text = "Yes" And (RBL <> 0 Or CBL <> 0)  Then
    Exit Sub
End If
```